# Make multiple JSONArray rows into one single row by grouping with some other column in postgresql

Tags: postgresql, aggregate-functions

I have a view from a query `select * from table` which returns the below data

[image]

I want to group by the name column which have same name and merge the JSONArray column like mentioned below

[image]

Comment: Sample data is better presented as [formatted text](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/251362) (e.g. so that someone who wants to help you can copy & paste the sample data). See [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/81852) for some tips on how to create nice looking tables.

Comment: Can't you do the needed aggregation already in that view?

Answer (score 3):

One way to do this, is to unnest the arrays and then aggregate them back:

```
select t.id, t.name, jsonb_agg(a.e)
from the_table t
  cross join lateral jsonb_array_elements(t.json_array) as a(e)
group by t.id, t.name;
```

---

If you do that a lot, a custom aggregate makes this a bit easier to user (but probably not faster)

```
create function jsonb_array_combine(p_one jsonb, p_two jsonb)
  returns jsonb
as
$$
  select jsonb_agg(e)
  from (
    select e
    from jsonb_array_elements(p_one) as o(e)
    union all
    select e
    from jsonb_array_elements(p_two) as t(e)
  ) t
$$
language sql 
immutable;

create aggregate jsonb_array_agg(jsonb) 
(
  SFUNC = jsonb_array_combine(jsonb, jsonb),
  STYPE = jsonb
);
```

Then you can use it like this:

```
select t.id, t.name, jsonb_array_agg(t.json_array)
from the_table t
group by t.id, t.name;
```

Comment: Can this be achieved without using functions?

Comment: @JohnsonAnthony That is written as first solution

Comment: @Akhilesh Mishra yeah i noticed now.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name it is working as mentioned in the first solution

Comment: in that case use `jsonb_agg(a.e order by a.e->>'rollnumber')` insteat of `jsonb_agg(a.e)`